# How can i write this statement better without repeating myself, it calls for values using simple html dom

Tags: php, foreach, simple-html-dom

I have this block code, it works fine, but i feel i am repeating myself so much, and it slows down the results when they come back. I'm using simple html dom to get the results. How can I do this as efficiently as possible?

```
$html = file_get_html( $urlfix );

// now lets go through all results to see what we get

$links = array();
foreach ( $html->find( 'div.mozaique div.thumb-block ' ) as $a ) {
    $links[] = $a->id;
}

// this will return  images

$datasrc = 'data-src';
$links2 = array();
foreach ( $html->find( 'div.mozaique div.thumb-block img ' ) as $a ) {
    $links2[] = $a->$datasrc;
}

// this will return the links


$links3 = array();
foreach ( $html->find( 'div.mozaique div.thumb-block div.thumb a ' ) as $a ) {
    $links3[] = $a->href;
}

// print_r($links3);

$links4 = array();
foreach ( $html->find( 'div.mozaique div.thumb-under p.title a ' ) as $a ) {
    $links4[] = $a->title;
}

// this will return another set of links

$vidoid = 'data-id';

$links5 = array();
foreach ( $html->find( 'div.mozaique div.thumb-block  ' ) as $a ) {
    $links5[] = $a->$vidoid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function & call it multiple times.

e.g:

```
function get_list($html, $find, $element) {
    $list = array();
    foreach ( $html->find($find) as $a ) {
        $list[] = $a->$element;
    }
    return $list;
}

$links = get_list($html, 'div.mozaique div.thumb-block ', 'id');
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back, i can see what you are trying to say, im not sure how to do it exactly, my confusion comes from the fact that the foreach statements i call are different, how would the full code look like. let me try with what you have just given methough.